# How to do persistent data on Front End?

Tags: front-end, cache, cookies, notices

I´m doing a plugin with a member system. I need to :

1. display notices ( error, warning, info ) for visitors when they fill the form to subscribe. To match with my core project, I need a system with a unique vistor ID store on a cookie to show notices or maybe a persistent cache object.
2. keep some user data during the process with several steps.

What is the best practice (framework compatibility, security ...) for Wordpress to do this ?

Comment: Is this all during a multi step form?

Comment: @TomJNowell yes, There are 3, 4 steps and a Paypal step as well. Even if I´m doing a front-end form checking, I add a server side form checking which potentialy send notices and redirect to the same step for example.

Comment: @TomJNowell For information, I use transient API to do the same on the admin but i´m using the user id.

Comment: For most of that you don't need to persist the data, using hidden fields and filling them in with the data from previous pages would solve the problem

Comment: @TomJNowell I would like to persist data because one step is on the paypal website.